# Understanding Cake PHP routes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm coming from Laravel and now I have a work to do based on Cake 3. I need an help to understanding routing. The application uses CRUD to generate API for a Angular5 app. The routes.php php is this:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Routes configuration
 *
 * In this file, you set up routes to your controllers and their actions.
 * Routes are very important mechanism that allows you to freely connect
 * different URLs to chosen controllers and their actions (functions).
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;

Router::defaultRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);

Router::scope($baseScope, function ($routes) {

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'App', 'action' => 'welcome']);
    $routes->connect('/getConfig', ['controller' => 'App', 'action' => 'getConfig']);

    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

/**
 * Load all plugin routes.  See the Plugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
Plugin::routes();
```

I need to know which method for example, respond to users/add route.... Inside the user controller I didn't get any add method...

Comment: Read the manual and do the tutorials? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html

Answer (score 1):

> It's obvious to get confusion with routing if you are came from
>   Laravel.
>
> CakePhp's routing is different but easier with Laravel routing in some
>   ways.

*In Laravel you have to define route for every method of the controller with the request type (get,post) just as you know.*

*But In CakePhp you don't need to write `route` for every method of the controller if you would like to go with CakePhp's conventions.*

> If your controller is UsersController and method is add, By CakePhp
>   convention route will be `'users/add'`.

Similarly,

```
Controller: Articles, Method:index => route: articles/index
Controller: Articles, Method:view_user_data => route: articles/view-user-data
```

More Here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

Also look at the power of cakephp conventions: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html